# How to import UNIQUE KEY from one table to another in a trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

(obs: *the ***ids** are not pk they are unique keys, the pks are a government "id" called **cpf****);

I want to create a function that reads the **id** in *table1 [person]* of a person and then insert this *[person].**id*** in *table 2 [went_to].**id*** (it is null at the moment)* if the ***cpf*** in *[went_to] matches the ***cpf*** in *[person]*

But the following error happens **(it never stops going because i don't know how to stoop the loop)**:

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION migrate_id() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
   LOOP
        UPDATE schema.went_to
        SET id = person.id 
        FROM schema.person 
        WHERE went.cpf = person.cpf;
   END LOOP;
END
$$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

But as it will be part of a trigger I don't think I need to create a Loop as long as I define the Trigger as to EACH ROW.

Then I tried without the loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION migrate_id() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN

        UPDATE schema.went_to
        SET id = person.id 
        FROM schema.person 
        WHERE went.cpf = person.cpf;

END
$$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

But it doesn't work because there is no return in the end of the function. So I tried to make a return in many ways but I failed in all my tries. I end up running out of ideas and I can't find the "answer" to my problem online, could someone help me?

I manage to get an "result" if I type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pa_migrarID_vp(OUT ID INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
```

But it gives null (because all the ids are already null)

Here is how I intend to use the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ADD_ID
    AFTER INSERT ON went_to
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE migrate_id();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer cannot work. You cannot update a row in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger because it has not been inserted yet.

Instead, assign to `NEW` directly:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.migrated_id()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO NEW.id  p.id 
   FROM   schema.person p
   WHERE  p.cpf = NEW.cpf;
END
$func$

CREATE TRIGGER add_it
BEFORE INSERT ON schema.went_to
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION schema.migrated_id();
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL Update trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271883/postgresql-update-trigger/25273309#25273309)
- [Postgresql before update/insert trigger doesn't appear to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688470/postgresql-before-update-insert-trigger-doesnt-appear-to-work/7688508#7688508)
- [A value of a NEW record seems to be kept as the OLD record between two if/elseif blocks in a PostgreSQL trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262640/a-value-of-a-new-record-seems-to-be-kept-as-the-old-record-between-two-if-elseif/69269687#69269687)

Answer (score 0):

I just manage to solve it!! At least I think so, so I will run some tests and then I will post the answer here in case someone else needs help with it too.

The code is the same but I just did not made the function into a trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.migrated_id() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

    UPDATE schema.went_to
    SET id = person.id 
    FROM schema.person 
    WHERE went.cpf = person.cpf;

END
$$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Then I just made the trigger and it WORKED!

```
 CREATE TRIGGER ADD_ID
        AFTER INSERT ON schema.went_to
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE migrated_id();
```

It WORKED!!

Comment: This cannot work.

Comment: my bad, i actually used after, not before

Comment: Now it "works". But it's needlessly convoluted. Consider the superior approach I posted.

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible, thanks!